# How can I find the exact users browser with php

Tags: php

I am currently using :

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
```

but I am gettinng :

```
User Agent : Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36
```

What I am looking for is a way to find the exact broser like chrome or IE8. Is there a solution in php to do this

Comment: why does this question get an upvote? there is clearly no research effort if you can google the answer in 10 seconds with the most obvious words...

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the function [`get_browser()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php)

Comment: Bah... beaten by a few seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [get_browser()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) function.

Comment: The get_browser() still outputs :Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36 Warning: get_browser(): browscap ini directive not set. Thanks

Comment: @BarryConnolly You'll have to [download](http://tempdownloads.browserscap.com/) a browsercap file and place it in the location of your choice. then add this line to php.ini

Answer (score 1):

see [`get_browser()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php#101125) ............

Answer (score 1):

here is full list for user agents

http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/browser_ids.htm

Answer (score 1):

**get_browser()** method will tells the user's browser

Example:

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\n\n";

$browser = get_browser(null, true);
print_r($browser);
?>
```

Output:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7) Gecko/20040803 Firefox/0.9.3
```